# Microservices - handling asynchronous data creation in frontend application

Tags: rest, asynchronous, frontend, microservices, message-queue

I have problem, that is pretty crucial, but I couldn't find good answer to it for a while.

I have a microservice-based backend with the gateway, a few other microservices, and Kafka brokers.
Gateway offers synchronous REST API for reads/queries and asynchronous for writes.

Write scenario looks as follows. The gateway returns 202 Accepted status and publishes event e.g. CreateItem to Kafka. Item service subscribes to this kind of event, creates an item and emits ItemCreated event.

**My problem is how to handle such scenario on frontend side.**

The most basic approach I thought about is to route to the items list page and poll for items, so the newly created items show there eventually (maybe with some kind of indicator, that shipment creation is being processed) but it's kinda stupid.

I also thought about pushing writes from frontend over WebSocket to the gateway and on ItemCreated event gateway would push that info back to the client, but it doesn't resolve the problem - what to show to the user?

On the other hand, I can use the WebSocket solution and show some loading screen with an indeterminate progress bar, when waiting for a response over a socket, but that would make the write effectively synchronous - at least on the frontend side. Just as well I could make the write HTTP POST endpoint synchronous on the Gateway side and return the response only after the ItemCreated event has been received.

So, what would be the best solution to that problem? Are some of these I listed any good?

Comment: Do you really need asynchronous write? If so your websocket solution seems good but it depends how to handle your task in front-end. By the way how much it takes when you trigger write process?

Comment: Asynchronous write is a thing i dont want to change. Could you please explain what do you mean with "how much it takes"?

Comment: I mean, How much time it takes that write operation?

Comment: Whole process - few hundreds millis. I dont want to restrict to this particular case though. I'm looking for solution that would be also good if the write would take more time.